# Assigning Excel worksheet name when writing list of dataframes from R studio to Excel with write_xlsx

Tags: excel, dataframe, worksheet

I am relatively new into R programming and I have a question if and if so how it is possible to write Multiple Dataframes in R into multiple Worksheets in Excel without using write.xlsx because of the Java blocking at my office computer

I have 4 csv files in a directory

The names of these CSV files is read into a variable call 'Network'

...

```
Network = list.files(pattern ="*.csv")
```

...

Because the data coming out of PowerFactory is written in a csv with two lines (first row columntitle) spread over 700 columns in the csv files several actions are applied to he files themselves when they are also 1 by 1 read into R Studio with a FOR loop and the actions are applied to the data.
At the end of the FOR loop the resulting dataframe with the resulting 4 columns of the alternated orignal csv file is added to a list called "Totaal"

This list "Totaal" contains at the end 4 dataframes or as many files that where in the orignal directory.

After that the complete list "Totaal" is written to Excel with the function Write_xlsx and within this Excel file there are 4 worksheets created with the contains of the 4 dataframes. I use this because write.xlsx doesn't run on my office computer because Java is disabled.

What I would like to happen is that de worksheets in the Excel file receive (a part of) the original filename of the original CSV files and those names are stored in the variable 'Network'.

Hopefully somebody can give me the answer how to assign the desired names to the worksheets in the resulting Excel file.

...

```
Network = list.files(pattern ="*.csv")
files = sapply(Network, read_csv2)
```

...

The data is changed and transponed in the correct format

#The reslting data is put into one resulting dataframe per original csv file
df_Hosting_Capacity <- data.frame(MSR[,1], Max_Host_Cap, Max_Bel, Max_Vol, Min_Vol,Deelnetten[[n]])

#Depending on the number (n) of original csv files a resulting list is with (n) dataframes

...

```
if(n==1){
Totaal <- list(df_Hosting_Capacity)
} else {
  Totaal <- df_Hosting_Capacity
}
```

...

#The result "Totaal" is writen into an Excel file. And here I would like to define also the name of the (n) created worksheets. Ideal the worksheets contain (a part of) the name of the original csv file.

...

```
write_xlsx(Totaal,"Resultats.xlsx")
```

...

Many thanks in advance for your advice.